# Apache virtualHost ignored or pointing to the default one

Tags: macos, apache, configuration, virtualhost

I'm trying to setup my Apache on OSX, but I'm not able to make my local url 'awr.local' point to the correct path. I mean whether I type http://localhost or http://awr.local, it always shows me the index.html page in my 'localhost' vhost path.
I've restarted my httpd service countless times, with or without sudo.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :'|

I've been following a tutorial (https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions), here are the steps about Apache :

## Disabling the bundled Apache and installing the one from homebrew :

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
brew install httpd
```

## Then, some httpd.conf modifications :

```
# changed Listen 8080 to :
Listen 80
[...]
# changed DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www" to :
DocumentRoot "/Users/wallace/dev/default"
[...]
# changed <Directory "/usr/local/var/www"> to :
<Directory "/Users/wallace/dev/default">
[...]
# changed AllowOverride None to :
AllowOverride All
# uncommented :
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
[...]
# changed
# User _www
# Group _www
# to :
User wallace
Group staff
[...]
# added the missing line :
ServerName localhost
```

Until this point everything seemed to be working fine, I've installed PHP and MariaDB without any problem.

Then came the virtual hosts part :

## Some other httpd.conf modifications :

```
# uncommenting these lines
LoadModule vhost_alias_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
[...]
Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

## Editing the file /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/wallace/dev/default"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/wallace/dev/awr"
    ServerName awr.local
</VirtualHost>
```

## The /etc/hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       awr.local
::1             awr.local
```

## The output of 'httpd -S' :

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:25)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:25)
         port 80 namevhost awr.local (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:30)
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Users/wallace/dev/default"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="wallace" id=501 not_used
Group: name="staff" id=20 not_used
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, today when I was preparing to try the answer of Juan, I had something new : instead of serving me the localhost, the awr.local url showed me a 403 forbidden. After a new research & doc reading, I managed to make it work like this :

## My /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file :

The **Require all granted** is the most important part.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/wallace/dev/default"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/Users/wallace/dev/default">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/wallace/dev/awr"
    ServerName awr.local
    <Directory "/Users/wallace/dev/awr">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I had to restart Apache with **sudo** for it to work :

> sudo brew services stop httpd && sudo brew services start httpd

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and couldn't get it to work no matter what I tried. Stopping, starting or restarting httpd did not work. Even though httpd -S always reported the correct settings, all browsers loaded the default docroot, regardless of the virtualhost settings. Then I noticed something strange. After stopping httpd with `brew services stop httpd` I reloaded localhost in the browser and it still loaded without a problem. This gave me the idea to `sudo killall httpd` then start it again with `brew services start httpd`. After this, all was fine.

Answer (score 2):

Considering how much time I spent on this, I will be dropping my own fix too.
First of all I noticed that all server names using the `127.0.0.1` IP always points to the default directory. I edited my custom domain to use `127.0.1.1` in `/etc/hosts`.
In `/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, edited it according to Alfred's answer as I was initially getting a 403 too.

Files looks something like this;

`/etc/hosts`:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       customdomain.local # note: 127.0.1.1
127.0.1.2       customdomain2.local # note: 127.0.1.2 (will increment for each new domain)
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
::1             customdomain.local
::1             customdomain2.local # this part is equally important though I am not sure why
```

`/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost customdomain.local:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@customdomain.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/user/Projects/customdomain/public"
    ServerName customdomain.local
    <Directory "/Users/user/Projects/customdomain/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Confirm that your Listen value in `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`is 80.

This might not be the best solution but should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have it setup (I've made changes to match your configuration).
Besides awr.local must be in your /etc/hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1 or any other network interface you want to use.

```
<VirtualHost awr.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/wallace/dev/awr"
    ServerName awr.local
    <Directory "/Users/wallace/dev/awr">
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```